# Maps addition with key as a structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

```
    typedef struct A{
      string id;
      long date;
      // operator = and < overloading
    }Test;

Map<Test, double> testMap[2];
```

In code, the `testMap` array is filled with keys and values with some business logic.

I need to compute the total double value of both the maps for every `A.id` . Please note the summation should be based on only `A.id` not by the whole structure key. 
To achieve this i can apply the normal brute force approach using for loop and get the result.

But I am trying to find if any alternative solution for this problem that can optimize code. Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using this : Map<Test.id, double> testMap[2]; ?

Comment: For every id , we may have different transactions on different dates. So made the map key as a combination of id and date.

Comment: Seems like `map<string, pair<vector<double>, long>> test_map[2]` might work better in this specific case.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `std::array<std::map<Test, double>, 2> testMaps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to apply nested [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) twice, once to sum up the *arrays* and for each array to sum up the *map* contents:

```
struct Test
{
    string id;
    long date;
    bool operator<(Test const& test) const
    {
        if(date == test.date)
            return id < test.id;
        return date < test.date;
    }
};

double sum_per_id(std::array<std::map<Test, double>, 2> const& testMapArray,
    std::string const& id)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(testMapArray), std::end(testMapArray), 0.0,
    [&id](double d, std::map<Test, double> const& testMap)
    {
        return d + std::accumulate(std::begin(testMap), std::end(testMap), 0.0,
        [&id](double d, std::map<Test, double>::value_type const& p)
        {
            if(id == p.first.id)
                return d + p.second;
            return d;
        });
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::map<Test, double>, 2> testMapArray;

    testMapArray[0][{"A", 0}] = 0.1;
    testMapArray[0][{"B", 1}] = 0.2;

    testMapArray[1][{"A", 2}] = 0.3;
    testMapArray[1][{"B", 3}] = 0.4;

    std::cout << "sum: " << sum_per_id(testMapArray, "A") << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
sum: 0.4
```

Comment: In that case testMapArray[0][{"A", 0}] = 0.1; testMapArray[0][{"A", 1}] = 0.1; the scond key will override the first key. I think he wants his comparison based on id and data.

Comment: @user1438832 Yes you are right. I was focusing on the summation rather than what his implementation of the key comparator might be. Fixed.

Comment: I find it a great approach!!

Comment: I am using vs2010. I get errors related to lambda expressions. I never used c++11 earlier. So i hope the above approach can be implemented only in higher version of visual studio.

Comment: @user1706047 The code could be modified for earlier versions of the compiler by creating *function objects* to replace the *lambdas*. But it's not as clear or succinct as using *lambdas*. If you can't use `C++11` then I recommend just constructing the loops manually.